# Automatically converting fetch() to fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

Tags: php, pdo

I've made this function in my code:

```
function fetch() {
   return fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
}
```

to only do

```
$query->fetch()
```

and it will automatically become

```
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. What’s the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up your database connection to use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` by default:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

The function doesn’t work because you just can’t extend existing classes (well, without RunKit hackery) in PHP.

Comment: how this will work ? i mean how i will use the `fetch()` after i set the default

Comment: @UseR: Exactly like you wanted to: `$query->fetch()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the query as a parameter to the function:

```
<?php
function fetch($q)
{
    return $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
}
fetch($query);
?>
```